# HTML - Canvas element get Base64 data at same scale of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I found that to get the base64 data from a HTML canvas, you had to do    `canvas.toDataURL();`. The problem with this, is that when it gives you the base64, it is scaled to the generic 300 x 150 canvas size, but the actual canvas is 600 x 100. Is there a way to strech the image to be 600 x 100, or to export it in the base64 as such? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `toDataURL` is not related to size. It just gives string equivalent of your canvas. `300x150` is when you don't give size in constructor, if you provide the size, it will generate the image with the provided size

Comment: post your code if you have some problem in it

Comment: @Gaurav Chaudhary I tried that in a css width: 600px; It did not work

Comment: How do you get to know, it is scaling? Are you saving it as `JPG` image. If you provide the code, then I will try to help!

Comment: I am saving it as a png, I'll get to uploading it!

Comment: Wait, I see now that It wasn't saving at the right size because I had the width and height defined in css, not html

Comment: yes, you need to define it in html or through javascript. Is it resolved now?

Comment: Yes its resolved

Answer (score 0):

I had the width and height defined in CSS not HTML, so the document wasn't registering the widths and heights.
 Here is the updated code below:

```html
<body>
<script>
var granmoe = 0;
var hai = 5;
var runnin = 0;
while(runnin != hai){
 var can = document.createElement("canvas");
 can.id = "canvasite"
 can.style = "width: 150px; height: 100px; display:none;"
 document.body.appendChild(can);
 c = document.getElementById('canvasite'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var x = 0
    if(runnin == 0){
  var endheight = c.height/2
 }
    var y = endheight;
 var widd = 0
 while(widd != c.width){
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+0+","+255+","+0+","+(255/255)+")";
  ctx.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 );
  var ychan = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  if(ychan == 1){
   var y=y+2
  }else if(ychan == 2){
   var y=y+1
  }else if(ychan == 3){
   var y=y-1
  }else if(ychan == 4){
   var y=y-2
  }else{
   var y=y
  }
  var hig = y
  while(hig != c.height){
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+0+","+255+","+0+","+(255/255)+")";
   ctx.fillRect( x, hig, 1, 1 );
   var hig = hig+1
  }
  var widd = widd+1
  var x=x+1
 }
    {
 var endheight = y
 var runnin = runnin+1
 document.getElementById('canvasite').setAttribute('id','nAn')
 var imgm = document.createElement("img");
 imgm.src = c.toDataURL();
    imgm.id = "imageitem"
    imgm.style = "display:none;"
 document.body.appendChild(imgm)
 var xid = granmoe*(300*(1/hai));
 if(granmoe == 0){
  var cansfoo = document.createElement("canvas")
  cansfoo.id = "fullimage";
  cansfoo.style = 'width: '+(hai*150)+'px; height: 100px; display:none;'
  document.body.appendChild(cansfoo);
 }
 var ci=document.getElementById("fullimage");
 var ctxi=ci.getContext("2d");
 var imd=document.getElementById("imageitem");
 ctxi.drawImage(imd,xid,0,(300*(1/hai)),180);
 //end
 var granmoe=granmoe+1
 document.getElementById("imageitem").setAttribute('id','non');
}
}
var base64 = ci.toDataURL();
var bass = document.createElement("img");
bass.src = base64
bass.id = "resiz"
bass.style = "display:none;"
document.body.appendChild(bass);
{
  var resize = document.createElement("canvas")
  resize.id = "resize";
        resize.width = (hai*150);
        resize.height = 100;
  resize.style = 'display:none;'
  document.body.appendChild(resize);
 var re=document.getElementById("resize");
 var res=re.getContext("2d");
     var imag=document.getElementById("resiz");
 res.drawImage(imag,0,50,(hai*150),50);
    document.write(resize.toDataURL());
    }
</script>
</body>
```